# 720° Panoramic Roaming Technology in Indoor Display

Tags: three.js

i want to use threejs to Indoor-Panoramic-Roaming

effect like walked from one room to another room

Object 720° panoramic roaming technology has been widely used in outdoor panoramic roaming production, but the research on indoor panoramic production is few.